# Activerecord: Transfer ruby methods to sql-land

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following schema in a rails application
[image]

I have pages which have many load_times (which it is a polymorphic associations). I want to get the most recent `created_at` load_time for each page and then catch the max load_time field number from them (hope the same name field won't confuse you). This is what I currently have which works but uses ruby methods:

```
pages.includes(:load_times).group(:resource_id).select("load_times.load_time, max(load_times.created_at) as date").reject{|lt| lt.load_time.nil?}.sort_by { |pg| pg.load_time.load_time }.last
```

How can I transfer the `reject` and `sort_by` ruby methods to sql land?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
pages
.joins(:load_times)
.group(:resource_id)
.select("pages.*, load_times.load_time, MAX(load_times.created_at) as date")
.where.not(load_times: { load_time: nil })
.order("load_times.load_time")
.last
```

Notice that the `where.not` is Rails >= 4 only. If you are in Rails 3 you can replace that by `where("load_times.load_time IS NOT NULL")`

---

After clarifying the desired result in the comments, this is the query to obtain the Page object with the slowest load_time of all, taking only into account the most recent `load_time` record's load_time. Please note that you can normally obtain that result in your having clause with `MAX(load_times.created_at)` or with `MAX(load_times.id)` indistinguishably, being the latter a bit more efficient. If you do, change all references to `created_at` by `id`.

```
pages
.joins(:load_times)
.where.not(load_times: { load_time: nil })
.group('load_times.created_at')
.having('load_times.created_at = MAX(load_times.created_at)')
.order('load_times.load_time DESC')
.first
```

---

*EDIT*

After some more research (yeah, I took this personally ;)), I finally got your query working. You need to join the `load_times` table twice, using the last row for each `Page` in the join conditions.

Also, you need to use a single column to identify the last entry of the `load_times`, for the second join. `created_at` may not work properly, since your `load_times` table might have two entries with the same `created_at`. Maybe it's not your case, but just in case I used `id`, since it has the same order as `created_at` and it's unique.

Also, I removed the `where.not(load_times: { load_time: nil })` bit, since I assume you want to prime getting the last `load_time` element over it having a `load_time` attribute.

At last, I assumed a polymorphic association, hence the `resource_type = 'Page'`.

Here it goes:

```
pages
.joins(:load_times)
.joins("INNER JOIN (SELECT l1.page_id, MAX(l1.id) AS max_id FROM load_times as l1 GROUP BY l1.page_id) l2 ON load_times.page_id = l2.page_id AND load_times.id = l2.max_id AND resource_type = 'Page'")
.order("load_times.load_time DESC")
.first
```

Thanks for a thought-provoking question, I learned quite a bit here.

Comment: The `where.not` is throwing an error as it tries to find a `load_time` field on page. Also the order for some reason doesn't work, I tried it, I guess it has to do with the select which has sql. Maybe I have to replace the max.

Comment: Fixed the first. What error are you having for the second?

Comment: The 2nd one has one strange error: It doesn't order correctly with this field. The specific field is a typical decimal field in a mysql db. I don't know if it is a problem with the names because if I just put `resource_id` it does the ordering correctly.

Comment: Can you show me the SQL produced? => ``pages.includes(:load_times).blabla.order("load_times.load_time").to_sql``

Comment: It shows the following sql query:
"SELECT load_times.load_time, max(load_times.created_at) as date FROM `pages`  WHERE `pages`.`account_id` = 1 AND `pages`.`account_id` = 1 AND (`load_times`.`load_time` IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY resource_id  ORDER BY load_times.load_time" 
Which seems fine... I've tried with `ASC` and `DESC` and it doesn't work. I think it is a name or a field type problem as if I order by another field (like resource_id) it works the ordering.

Comment: Not it doesn't work, it returns nil page id and when I am adding the id to select it still isn't correct the ordering.

Comment: Do you need the page ``id``? You didn't mention that before ... can you add all the required fields you need to the question? I'd suggest you remove the ``select`` statement and calculate your ``date`` after the query is executed.

Comment: I added the pages columns to the query, so now you should be getting the ``Page`` objects with the ``date`` accessible.

Comment: And you need ... what exactly for a return?

Comment: I want the page which has the slowest load_time. I want the same functionality as the current one I have, I just want to replace both of the ruby methods with sql way.

Comment: So you need the query to return a single ``Page`` object, sorted by the slowest load_time?

Comment: Yes, but it should only take into account the latest load_time for each page.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you need **a)** a collection of Page objects, sorted by the slowest load_time, **b)** a single Page object which is the one with the slowest load_time of all, **c)** the load_time (a value) from the slowest Page?

Comment: Great! I updated my answer with the query to obtain that ``Page``. Way simpler than first devised ... ;)

Comment: I want to check only the latest load_time of the page. If I have a big load_time but the latest is small, I don't want that page. Please read my description and try to understand what my current code does.

Comment: Hmm then it's not **b)** what you want ... that is why I was trying to clarify, because I din't really understand what your intend was ;) Ok, I think I got it at last. Let me update the question.

Comment: Well, I think we're quite there this time. Please test it and tell me if it suite your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your try, but it still isn't ordering correctly the load_time.

Comment: Well, here comes the result of my last research. I hope I nailed it this time!

Comment: Yes, the last one worked (I had to replace the page_id with resource_id, but it is working!) :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on the work of @dgilperez, I think this may return the values that you're aiming for:

```
pages
.joins(:load_times)
.where.not(load_times: { load_time: nil })
.group(:resource_id)
.select('pages.*, MAX(load_times.load_time) as load_time, MAX(load_times.created_at) as max_created_at')
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, it doesn't return the page, I tried to put only the select with no luck.